# php processing a dynamically generated form

Tags: php, javascript, post, get

I'm using php to generate an html page that displays blog/thread items, and I am using javascript to show/hide some of the details.  The problem is that I am generating unique IDs for each set of hidden content, which contains a form to process the input.  In processing the form, I need to know which blog item was edited - I want to use $_POST.  I'm pretty new to javascript, and I'm thinking that there is probably a solution I can use there.

I want the post to save the text to the mysql database (so call one of my php functions that I have working) and tell me what the text was and what the threadId is.

Here is the php code snipet, where $threadDetailItem is an array that has my thread data in it.

```
   foreach ($threadData as $threadDetailItem)
   {
    // display main line (a bunch of code here ...)


    // append button to edit or delete the post for admin
    if ( isset ($_SESSION['isAdmin']) && $_SESSION['isAdmin'] == 'Y'){
        // edit link opens content, and delete pops up a confirmation box
        $el = sprintf ("editThreadLink_%d", $threadDetailItem['blogThreadId']);
        $ec = sprintf ("editThreadContent_%d", $threadDetailItem['blogThreadId']);
        $link1 = sprintf ("<a id=\"%s\" href=\"javascript:toggle('%s', '%s');\">+</a>", $el, $ec, $el);
        $msg .= sprintf ("<li id=\"field6\">%s</li>\n", $link1);
    } 
    $msg .= "</ul>\n";
    echo $msg;

    // now that the row is printed, lets add the hidden content if admin so they can edit
    if ( isset ($_SESSION['isAdmin']) && $_SESSION['isAdmin'] == 'Y'){
        // hidden content to enable editing of the posting
        $msg = sprintf ("<div id=\"%s\" style=\"display: none\">\n", $ec);
        echo $msg;

        echo "<form name=\"form\" method=\"post\" action=\"\">\n";
        $msg = sprintf ("<textarea id=\"%s\" name=\"%s\">%s</textarea>\n", 
            $ec, $ec, $threadDetailItem['threadTitle']);
        echo $msg;
        $msg = sprintf ("<button type=\"submit\"> %s</button>\n", $lang->get('BLOG POST'));
        echo $msg;
        echo "</form>\n";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Suggestions on good ways to handle this event are much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

The fields in the data are:   blogThreadId, threadTitle, username, createdOn, lastUpdated, displayed (not used) and threadDetails (array containing the posting information).

Comment: What event do you what to handle ?? also add sample `$threadData` data

Comment: I'm looking at adding a hidden field to my form that will enable the regular post to know the treadId, which is the event when the user updates the field.

Comment: the $threadData is an instance that can be printed out in my debug function that I put in at the bottom of my question.  thanks.

Comment: You want to save the form input values to the database when you click the button, right?

Comment: yes - I will save the value to the DB and then redisplay the page.  I think I can do this w/ the hidden field and will circle back when/if that works.

Comment: I was able to use $_POST along w/ the ID in a hidden field to enable my php scripts to know which thread was being edited.  It is working now.  Thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use $_POST along w/ the ID in a hidden field to enable my php scripts to know which thread was being edited.  It is working